# Convert excel sheet to Json using Kendo

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I have an upload functionality where user uploads excel sheet and backend api is expecting the result in JSON format of the entire data as input as shown below

```
[{
"LineNumber": "1",
"Parma": 123,
"PartNumber": 234,
"TestQual": "AQ",
"UOM": "LIT",
"TestCode": "RME",
"Weight1": 234,
"Weight2": 235,
"Weight3": 10,
"IsValid": true,
"ValidationMessage": "test"

}, {
"LineNumber": "2",
"Parma": 321,
"PartNumber": 455,
"TestQual": "AQ",
"UOM": "LIT",
"TestCode": "RME",
"Weight1": 290,
"Weight2": 200,
"Weight3": 20,
"IsValid": true,
"ValidationMessage": "test"

}]
```

Likewise if the excel has 100 records , we need JSON array with all the data.

I have checked for available options in Kendo but I could not find anything, help me with your ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Well, it's not a custom to process files on the client-side, but if you cant change API then use some external library for opening files on the client-side, build JSON then send request to API. Its more JS, TS, Angular question than Kendo question. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48112236/read-excel-file-in-angular-2

Answer (score 1):

This may be a late reply, but answering hoping it helps other users.

There is a npm package which converts excel input to JSON data , repository details is available at [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-excel-to-json).

Since it is a private package, enterprise usage should be limited and one must be vigilant about support or upgrades.

Comment: Thank you. I have handled the requirement on the server side, so I get a JSON response on the post service call.